# Python input words and count repeated words in there

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

hello I have this question to write a program. Write a program that can count the number of occurrences of a string as a substring of another string. Assume that the entered string only consists of lowercase letters (a - z), and string 1 is not longer than string 2. For input and output formats, the program can follow the following example.

here is an example of the output:

1. Enter string length 1: 4
2. Enter string 1: haha
3. Enter string length 2: 8
4. Enter string 2: hahahahahaha
5. String 1 appears 5 times.

any help would be greatly appreciated. thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it:

```
string.count(substring)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).